# Vaadin - how to log (on production?)

Tags: spring-boot, logging, vaadin

artists,
can you provide me a way how to log a Vaadin / Spring Boot 3 app on production?

It would be great to get log statements in the console of the Chrome browser..

Comment: Could you please be more specific, what you are trying to do? Do you want to `console.log("Hello, World")` and it does not work in your production-build?

Comment: @cfrick exactly.. could you please explain how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
public class ConsoleLog {
    public static void log(Page page, String log) {
        page.executeJs("console.log('" + log + "');");
    }
}
```

call

```
  ConsoleLog.log(UI.getCurrent().getPage(), "Log statement");
```